# Python Selenium: can't figure out xpath to clickable link element in span tag

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using selenium python and have tried more than a dozen ways to find a clickable link element from a span tag but have been unsuccessful. I've tried using xpath, by link text, partial link text, and other suggestions researched.

The last 3 attempts using:

1. `browser.find_element_by_link_text("Web Time Clock-Eastern").click()`
2. `element = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Clock-Eastern')`
3. `browser.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@span]/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]button'))).click()`

I've provided image of the inspected element html below:

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ULk2fxCRUohz21VlfrrlX8iSvmvSAJ8k/view?usp=sharing]

I expect to locate an element I can pass click method to open corresponding web page.

Comment: Get the xpath of the anchor, not the span

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cardLinks a[href*='php/timeclock/WEB'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cardLinks']//a[contains(@href, 'php/timeclock/WEB')]/span[text()='Web Time Clock-Eastern']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below xpath.

```
 //span[normalize-space(.)='Web Time Clock-Eastern']/parent::a
```

Comment: Make sure if the driver scope is matching with the  element scope (the main window, iframe or child window)

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons for using [XPath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) is when you don’t have a suitable id or name attribute for the element you wish to locate.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='cardLinks']/div/a").click()
```